# editConvert video into binary dataset in python

Tags: python, video, binary

I am new in python, i recently became learn it. I want convert my videofiles into binary dataset. I work in console of python 3.7

```
videoFile = "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\myvideo" # folder with my videofiles
```

i do so

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\myvideo")# folder with my video
 
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

then i get the error

```
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>>
... cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\myvideo")
  File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in positio
n 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>>>
... while(True):
...     ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Why i can't do it?
How can i correct convert my video files into binary dataset in csv
all video in separately csv dataset

## edit

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\cv2\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
>>>
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\myvideo")# folder with my v
ideo
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in positio
n 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>>>
>>> while(True):
...     ret, frame = cap.read()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'cap' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to install the modules: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/, https://scipy.org/install.html. You should already have pip installed if you are running Python 2.7.9+ or Python 3.4+.

Comment: @PythonNewb, it was installed, but the error is not fixed

Comment: `ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль` : this means something was not properly installed. Try to reinstall `numpy` and `cv2` modules.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are using a normal string as a path
Just put r before your normal string it converts normal string to raw string:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r"C:\Users\gokul\PycharmProjects\GpuTry\sample.mp4")
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(frame)
```

The above code worked perfect.

Comment: in my folder there are many vidoes)) How can  i load all my video and then convert to binary dataset. And you didn't show how import data to csv. :)